# How can I execute gulp without below error?

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

Thank you for your consideration.

I've downloaded angular project and am going to execute the project in my local.

I am using

- node 5.10.1
- npm 3.8.3
- gulp 3.9.1
- angular 1.3.0-rc.2

I'd like to know why this happened and how I can fix it.
Thank you for your any kind of help.

```
events.js:159
      throw err;
      ^

Error: Uncaught, unspecified "error" event. (Broken @import declaration of "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,700" - timeout)
    at DestroyableTransform.emit (events.js:157:17)
    at DestroyableTransform.onerror (D:\work\AngularJS\Work\init-project\src\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readabl
e.js:558:12)
    at emitOne (events.js:90:13)
    at DestroyableTransform.emit (events.js:182:7)
    at onwriteError (D:\work\AngularJS\Work\init-project\src\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:250:10)
    at onwrite (D:\work\AngularJS\Work\init-project\src\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:268:5)
    at WritableState.onwrite (D:\work\AngularJS\Work\init-project\src\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:10
6:5)
    at afterTransform (D:\work\AngularJS\Work\init-project\src\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:104:5)
    at TransformState.afterTransform (D:\work\AngularJS\Work\init-project\src\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transf
orm.js:79:12)
    at D:\work\AngularJS\Work\init-project\src\node_modules\gulp-minify-css\index.js:113:9
```

Comment: `Broken @import declaration of "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,700" - timeout` Can you try fetching that URL?

Comment: Thank you! SLaks I am afraid I can't guess what you mean.